# Fetch percentage of total records that have a particular value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table of people in my postgresql database. This table has a 'sex' column containing the values 'M' and 'F'. I would like to fetch the percentage of this table that has a sex of 'M'.

More specifically, I would like to fetch this percentage as part of a group by statement that groups the people by zip code (we have a zip code column) and returns the male percentage of each zip code.

This statement successfully fetches the number of males in the entire table.

```
select count(*) from contacts_6  and sex='M'
```

This statement successfully fetches the total number of people in each zip code and groups by zip code...

```
select home_zip,  count(*) as total from contacts_6 where home_zip != '' group by home_zip
```

This statement successfully fetches a dummy percentage calculated from a dummy value of 2.0 divided by the total number of people in each zip code and groups by zip code...

```
select home_zip,  ROUND(2.0 / count(*), 3) as stat from contacts_6 where home_zip != '' group by home_zip
```

How can I replace the dummy value 2.0 with the actual number of males in the zip code?

I have tried this...

```
select home_zip,  ROUND((select b from 
                    (select count(*) from contacts_6 where contact_id < 10000 and sex='M') as b )
                    / count(*), 3) as stat from contacts_6 where home_zip != '' group by home_zip
```

which returns the error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: record / bigint
>   LINE 9:       / count(*), 3) as stat from contacts_6 where home_zip ...
>                 ^
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Character: 695

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    home_zip,  
    1.0 * round(sum( (sex = 'M')::int ) / count(*), 3) as stat 
from contacts_6 
where home_zip != '' 
group by home_zip
```

`sum( (sex = 'M')::int )` counts how many records in the group have `sex = 'M'`; this works by converting the result of a condition (`true` or `false`) to an integer value (`1` or `0`) and the suming the values.

Since we are dealing with `0`/`1` values, another convenient way to do the computation is to use `avg()`:

```
select 
    home_zip,  
    round(avg( (sex = 'M')::int ), 3) as stat 
from contacts_6 
where home_zip != '' 
group by home_zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick. Is there a better way?

```
select home_zip,  ROUND(avg(case when sex = 'M' then 100.0 else 0.0 end), 3)
 as stat from contacts_6 where home_zip != ''  group by home_zip
```

I found the answer in another post, closed the page and don't have the URl in my browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
   sex, 
   round(count(*)*100/(select count(*) from contacts_6),2) AS Pucentage
from 
   contacts_6
group by  
   sex
having 
   sex = 'M'
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps. Your code also doesn't fit the question.

Comment: Hi, I see you're a new user. Code-only answers are considered undesirable on StackOverflow. For example, if someone didn't have the question in front of them, would your answer make sense? Probably not. Your question is being reviewed for deletion. Please add a little bit of text explaining your answer with some words.